# change tcp congestion control from CUBIC to HTCP

Tags: tcp, centos, centos7, congestion-control

I am trying to change the tcp congestion control on my Centos 7.

I checked what algorithm with:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control 
cubic
```

I want to change to htcp but when I check if it is available:

```
ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/ipv4/
ah4.ko   inet_diag.ko  ipip.ko       netfilter    udp_diag.ko              xfrm4_mode_tunnel.ko
esp4.ko  ipcomp.ko     ip_tunnel.ko  tcp_diag.ko  xfrm4_mode_beet.ko       xfrm4_tunnel.ko
gre.ko   ip_gre.ko     ip_vti.ko     tunnel4.ko   xfrm4_mode_transport.ko
```

So, first I didn't see the CUBIC and neither HTCP. How do I enable the HTCP congestion control.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little bit too late, but you can change the congestion control from `cubic` to `htcp` with:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=htcp
```

You may also check which congestion controls are allowed in your system with:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control
```

If you want to see which ones are available:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control
```